# Express doesn't recognize arrow syntax as a middleware with export in front (ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

First here is the code that is **working**:

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    //Log Err

    console.log(err.stack.red);

    //Retun message to user
    res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, err: err.message });
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

I get app.use() requires a middleware function error when I move the export in front of the const modifier

```
export const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    //Log Err

    console.log(err.stack.red);

    //Retun message to user
    res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, err: err.message });
};
```

Generated error:

```
TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:210:11)
```

Could someone explain to me why putting export in front of the errorHandler function generates the above error?

I have a .babelrc that transforms the syntax.  (I know it works since other es6 syntax works fine)

Comment: `export default` ?

Comment: How would that change the program?

Comment: What version of node are you using ? Not all version of node supports export/import syntax, it is very recent.

Comment: I am on v14.2.0, it should be close to the latest release as I did a clean install a few months ago

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is not satisfactory,
Though This would work

```html
module.exports = () => {
  return (err, req, res, next) => {
    //Log Err

    console.log(err.stack.red);

    //Retun message to user
    res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, err: err.message });
}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

and some things that work in react may not work in express because after all they both are different right from the starting line of the code.

(require is used in express)
(import is used in react)

Comment: Agreed, thats why I have babel.  It doesnt matter what syntax (as long as I stay consistent) I use as the rc file will convert it into the proper version

Answer (score -3):

First of all why would you export a const variable and secondly as you have used the keyword 'const' the variable cannot be changed. Try using 'var' and then export(provided you something to do with variable in any other file like the export default which we use in react)

Hope you got my point!

Comment: "First of all why would you export a const variable" — It is a pretty common approach

Comment: "as you have used the keyword 'const' the variable cannot be changed" — There isn't any code trying to change it

Comment: As Quentin said I have no need to change the function, and I'd prefer to not accidentally change it